# VS Code not able to resolve Springframework Data Redis related dependencies, however, project builds completely fine in Eclipse

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code, redis

I am using VS Code to compile and debug my Spring Boot Java project with help of Gradle. I recently added Redis dependency to my project. The project compiles in Eclipse, but throws error in VS Code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Same goes for stack traces.

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages screenshots of code, errors & data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this answer becomes helpful to you or not but,

Normally VS code is not comes with default configurational setting of spring boot.

Spring boot project not able to run without dependencies.
So Because of your project not able to find relevant dependencies so it is generate this errors.

It solved using download plugin of vscode-spring-initializer and / or others.

If you need more detail then,

Try recognize your spring boot project in different IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipes. You see that there is some extra files are there like following,

External Libraries - which handle by maven kind of tool for load dependency.
.iml file in intellij : File which handle development module(contain plugins, module and other details).

This files are not existing there so that it generate issue.(That are different based on IDE)

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently modified the *pom.xml* or *build.gradle* config file, you need right click on *pom.xml* or *build.gradle* file and then run the menu *"Update project configuration"* to force the language server to update the project configuration/classpath. Otherwise, the java language server cannot recognize the newly added dependency.